# Line break in method chains in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm attempting to put line breaks in the following method chain in VB.NET, but I have the syntax incorrect:

```
HasRequired(Function(x) x.Issue).WithMany(Function(x) x.EntityNotes).HasForeignKey(Function(x) x.IssueID)
```

I would like something similar to:

```
HasRequired(Function(x) x.Issue)
   .WithMany(Function(x) x.EntityNotes)
   .HasForeignKey(Function(x) x.IssueID)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In VB.Net, you used to always need `_` to continue a line.  This is now often optional, but can always be added:

```
HasRequired(Function(x) x.Issue) _
   .WithMany(Function(x) x.EntityNotes) _
   .HasForeignKey(Function(x) x.IssueID)
```

As of Visual Studio 2010, however, you can leave this off in many cases, and the compiler will correctly determine whether the new "line" is part of the preceeding line.

This is covered under [Typographic and Code Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew) in the language documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike C#, for instance, a line break delimits code in VB. So if you want to continue a statement across lines you need to use the `_` underscore symbol, like this

```
HasRequired(Function(x) x.Issue) _
    .WithMany(Function(x) x.EntityNotes) _
    .HasForeignKey(Function(x) x.IssueID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the dot on the previous line, then the compiler knows the expression is not complete:

```
HasRequired(Function(x) x.Issue).
   WithMany(Function(x) x.EntityNotes).
   HasForeignKey(Function(x) x.IssueID)
```